# How to get Windows XP to play a sound on mouse clicks

Tags: windows-xp, mouse, audio

Is it possible to play a sound each time the mouse button is pressed in Windows?

We have some touch screens PC's that run Windows XP, and would like them to beep when pressed so the users know they have registered the click. (the touch screen acts a the left mouse button)

I have looked in Sounds and Accessibility options but can not see anything that would work.

If there is nothing in windows that would do this is there any third party applications to do the same job. We don't need anything lavish just a simple click or beep would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to make a small [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script that emits PC speaker beeps on mouse button presses and releases:

```
~LButton::     SoundBeep, 261, 20
~LButton UP::  SoundBeep, 523, 20
~RButton::     SoundBeep, 392, 20
~RButton UP::  SoundBeep, 785, 20
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the "Start' button in the lower left corner of the monitor, then choose "Control Panel."
2. Click "Sounds, Speech and Audio Devices"
3. Click "Sounds and Audio Devices"
4. Click the "Sounds" tab if it is not selected already.
5. Find "Start Navigation" under the "Windows Explorer" category on the list of sounds, and click to highlight it.
6. Click the drop-down menu under "Sounds" and select "Windows XP Start" or "Windows Navigation Start."
7. Click "OK." Windows now plays a clicking sound when you navigate in Windows Explorer or Internet Explorer.

Comment: That only works if the user clicks on the desktop or Explorer though, right?  If they click in an app of some sort, then it won't.  (iirc)
That's fine of course if the OP's interface is web-based...

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately the application running on the computers is a propitiatory desktop app, and doesn't cause the sound to be player, the "Select" option works for some parts of the app but not all.

Comment: For some apps the sound cannot be changed with Windows or otherwise.  There are many holes in this way of assigning sounds.